# Ratio of subsequences of divergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a_n\in (0,\infty)$ and $\sum_{n\geq 1}a_n = \infty$. Can i find a subsequence of indices $\{n_k\}_{k\geq 1}$ such that
$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n_{k+1}} a_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}a_i} \rightarrow 1 \quad \wedge \quad \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}a_i} < \infty$$

Thank you for the help.

Edit: For example if $a_n\leq 1$ for all $n$, then i can choose $n_k = \inf \{ n: \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i \geq k^2\}$.

Comment: @zugzug that is not a counterexample because you can choose $n_k = k$. Then $\sum_{i = 1}^{n_{k + 1}}a_i = k + 1$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^{n_{k}}a_i = k$ and $(k + 1)/k \to 1$.

Comment: @0XLR In that case, the second sum is infinite which would violate the condition i set, so for his example, you would choose $n_k = k^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $a_n = 2^n$. Let $(n_k)$ be a subsequence indexing scheme i.e. $n_k < n_{k + 1}$ so that $n_k + 1 \leq n_{k + 1}$. Then because $\sum_{i = 1}^{N}a_i = \sum_{i = 1}^{N}2^i = 2^{N + 1} - 2$
$$
\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n_{k + 1}}a_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n_k}a_i} = \frac{2^{n_{k + 1} + 1} - 2}{2^{n_k + 1} - 2} \geq \frac{2^{n_k + 2} - 2}{2^{n_k + 1} - 2} = \frac{2 - \frac{2}{2^{n_k + 1}}}{1 - \frac{1}{2^{n_k + 1}}}
$$ So $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{n_{k + 1}}a_i}{\sum_{i = 1}^{n_k}a_i}$ is either divergent or converges to a number that is at least $2$. So for this sequence, the first condition is always violated for all possible subsequences.